# How to limit text width arabic paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an Arabic paragraph and want it to be ended in a same virtual place
(
like in engilsh
hi how are  you
good morning ev
)

something like this
any help with that

Comment: If it's just the same number of characters, you can use "max-width: 50ch" to get 50 characters in length (the width of 0). Is that what you're after?

Comment: but it is in Arabic >>> in this language you can't cut the word from the middle as English

Comment: Can you update your post with some more information, like how the texts are displayed? Add HTML + CSS and we can take it from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

```
.arabic-text{
    text-direction : rtl 
    and 
    text-align :right
}
```

beside to

```
width : 20ch
```

So the code fully will be

```
.arabic-text{
    text-direction : rtl 
    text-align :right
    width : 20ch
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).